Unable to parse JSON string obtained from attribute in a HTML tag in Python
I am making an AJAX call to an endpoint (I didn't create this API) where the response is in JSON form. Within the JSON there is an a key called content of type string. This content appears to me to be HTML data which contains some JSON inside. I want to be able to parse this JSON which is contained within the HTML data, but I keep getting the following error when I attempt to do a json.loads() of the string:
{JSONDecodeError}JSONDecodeError('Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)')

and I don't really understand why I am getting this error
Here is the JSON string I am trying to parse:
{\"name\":\"ThreadMainListItemNormalizer\",\"props\":{\"thread\":{\"threadId\":4369992,\"threadTypeId\":1,\"titleSlug\":\"sebamed-sale-extra-soft-baby-cream-ps239-anti-dandruff-shampoo-ps387\",\"title\":\"Sebamed sale - extra soft baby cream \£2.39 / anti dandruff shampoo \£3.87\",\"currentUserVoteDirection\":\"\",\"commentCount\":0,\"status\":\"Activated\",\"isExpired\":false,\"isNew\":true,\"isPinned\":false,\"isTrending\":null,\"isBookmarked\":false,\"isLocal\":false,\"temperature\":0,\"temperatureLevel\":\"\",\"type\":\"Deal\",\"nsfw\":false,\"deletedAt\":null,\"publishedAt\":1720003748,\"voucherCode\":\"\",\"link\":\"https://www.justmylook.com/sebamed-m583\",\"merchant\":{\"merchantId\":45518,\"merchantName\":\"Justmylook\",\"merchantUrlName\":\"justmylook.co.uk\",\"isMerchantPageEnabled\":true},\"price\":2.39,\"nextBestPrice\":0,\"percentage\":0,\"discountType\":null,\"shipping\":{\"isFree\":1,\"price\":0},\"user\":{\"userId\":2701300,\"username\":\"Manish_N\",\"title\":\"\",\"avatar\":{\"path\":\"users/raw/default\",\"name\":\"2701300_6\",\"slotId\":\"default\",\"width\":0,\"height\":0,\"version\":6,\"unattached\":false,\"uid\":\"2701300_6.raw\",\"ext\":\"raw\"},\"persona\":{\"text\":null,\"type\":null},\"isBanned\":false,\"isDeletedOrPendingDeletion\":false,\"isUserProfileHidden\":false}}}}

If I paste the above JSON string at this online JSON validator tool it says that it is invalid JSON, however, when I unescape the JSON using this tool I get the following output:
"name":"ThreadMainListItemNormalizer","props":{"thread":{"threadId":4369991,"threadTypeId":1,"titleSlug":"samsung-55-qn700c-neo-qled-8k-hdr-smart-tv","title":"Samsung 55\" QN700C Neo QLED 8K HDR Smart TV Sold by Reliant Direct FBA","currentUserVoteDirection":"","commentCount":0,"status":"Activated","isExpired":false,"isNew":true,"isPinned":false,"isTrending":null,"isBookmarked":false,"isLocal":false,"temperature":0.59,"temperatureLevel":"Hot1","type":"Deal","nsfw":false,"deletedAt":null,"publishedAt":1720003637,"voucherCode":"","link":"https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BWFNLPTP?smid=A2CN43WDI0AWCL","merchant":{"merchantId":1650,"merchantName":"Amazon","merchantUrlName":"amazon-uk","isMerchantPageEnabled":true},"price":999,"nextBestPrice":1198,"percentage":0,"discountType":null,"shipping":{"isFree":1,"price":0},"user":{"userId":2679277,"username":"ben.jammin","title":"","avatar":{"path":"users/raw/default","name":"2679277_1","slotId":"default","width":0,"height":0,"version":1,"unattached":false,"uid":"2679277_1.raw","ext":"raw"},"persona":{"text":null,"type":null},"isBanned":false,"isDeletedOrPendingDeletion":false,"isUserProfileHidden":false}}}}

which is in fact valid JSON. My issue then arises, when I try to replicate the unescape tool and try do unescape the string within Python.
I have tried the following solutions

Using ast.literal_eval() but I get the following error
{SyntaxError}SyntaxError('unexpected character after line continuation character', ('<unknown>', 1, 3, '{\\"name\\":\\"ThreadMainListItemNo...:null,\\"type\\":null},\\"isBanned\\":false,\\"isDeletedOrPendingDeletion\\":false,\\"isUserProfileHidden\\":false}}}}', 1, 0))


Using .encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape') method outlined here but after doing a json.loads() of the unescaped string I get the following error
{JSONDecodeError}JSONDecodeError('Invalid \\escape: line 1 column 224 (char 223)')



Here is the full API response as requested. I am interested in the value of the content key
UPDATE:
I think the issue is that I have some invalid escape characters in the string e.g. \£. I followed the solution here and it's resolved my issue.
Does anyone have any idea why this API might be including an escaped £ symbol?

Replace false with False -- you're writing Python, not JS.

Please [edit] to provide a [mre], what you're showing is valid as neither Python nor JSON.

Don't use ast.literal_eval() to parse JSON, or json.loads() to parse Python. There are many similarities, but they're not the same.

What you have suggests a JSON string which first has to be decoded to a JSON object, which can then be decoded a second time to produce a Python dict.

I believe this is stringified JSON from javascript's JSON.stringify() function, where it escapes double quotes and uses javascripts true, false, and null. If you were to hit this API from javascript you would use JSON.parse() (like this using your data) to bring it back to a javascript object. I can't imagine any good reason why an API would go with this format though. It's odd and feels broken.

Yes, the API is very broken with some questionable design choices, but it's what I have to work with unfortunately.

just use a plain str.replace - seems good enough in this case. Even if there is one escaped backslash, like in a\\"b, the replace strategy will still keep one backslash character:
new_json = old_json.replace(r'\"', '"')


I get the following error with this
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 2 column 224 (char 224)
Please refer to this minimal reproducible example using your solution here https://pastebin.com/YyREd5AD

I suggest you add the old_json in your minimal example to the question.
Yes, the problem is that there are other escape sequences that are bogus - JSON wise, in your data.  It is erroring because there is a backslash prefixing the pound character.
You may want to just replace all backslashes in your data for empty-strings them:  new_json = old_json.replace("\\", "")

Some of the back slashes are required however in the case of \" within a string. Please refer to this example string https://pastebin.com/UtJUxRRt and I have also added the full API response in the question as an edit

Here is one way to handle it:
import json

string = "{\"name\":\"ThreadMainListItemNormalizer\",\"props\":{\"thread\":{\"threadId\":4369992,\"threadTypeId\":1,\"titleSlug\":\"sebamed-sale-extra-soft-baby-cream-ps239-anti-dandruff-shampoo-ps387\",\"title\":\"Sebamed sale - extra soft baby cream \£2.39 / anti dandruff shampoo \£3.87\",\"currentUserVoteDirection\":\"\",\"commentCount\":0,\"status\":\"Activated\",\"isExpired\":false,\"isNew\":true,\"isPinned\":false,\"isTrending\":null,\"isBookmarked\":false,\"isLocal\":false,\"temperature\":0,\"temperatureLevel\":\"\",\"type\":\"Deal\",\"nsfw\":false,\"deletedAt\":null,\"publishedAt\":1720003748,\"voucherCode\":\"\",\"link\":\"https://www.justmylook.com/sebamed-m583\",\"merchant\":{\"merchantId\":45518,\"merchantName\":\"Justmylook\",\"merchantUrlName\":\"justmylook.co.uk\",\"isMerchantPageEnabled\":true},\"price\":2.39,\"nextBestPrice\":0,\"percentage\":0,\"discountType\":null,\"shipping\":{\"isFree\":1,\"price\":0},\"user\":{\"userId\":2701300,\"username\":\"Manish_N\",\"title\":\"\",\"avatar\":{\"path\":\"users/raw/default\",\"name\":\"2701300_6\",\"slotId\":\"default\",\"width\":0,\"height\":0,\"version\":6,\"unattached\":false,\"uid\":\"2701300_6.raw\",\"ext\":\"raw\"},\"persona\":{\"text\":null,\"type\":null},\"isBanned\":false,\"isDeletedOrPendingDeletion\":false,\"isUserProfileHidden\":false}}}}"
string = string.replace('false', '"False"').replace('true', '"True"').replace('null', '"None"').replace('\\', '')
result = json.loads(string)
print(result)

Result in terminal:
{'name': 'ThreadMainListItemNormalizer',
 'props': {'thread': {'threadId': 4369992,
   'threadTypeId': 1,
   'titleSlug': 'sebamed-sale-extra-soft-baby-cream-ps239-anti-dandruff-shampoo-ps387',
   'title': 'Sebamed sale - extra soft baby cream £2.39 / anti dandruff shampoo £3.87',
   'currentUserVoteDirection': '',
   'commentCount': 0,
   'status': 'Activated',
   'isExpired': 'False',
   'isNew': 'True',
   'isPinned': 'False',
   'isTrending': 'None',
   'isBookmarked': 'False',
   'isLocal': 'False',
   'temperature': 0,
   'temperatureLevel': '',
   'type': 'Deal',
   'nsfw': 'False',
   'deletedAt': 'None',
   'publishedAt': 1720003748,
   'voucherCode': '',
   'link': 'https://www.justmylook.com/sebamed-m583',
   'merchant': {'merchantId': 45518,
    'merchantName': 'Justmylook',
    'merchantUrlName': 'justmylook.co.uk',
    'isMerchantPageEnabled': 'True'},
   'price': 2.39,
   'nextBestPrice': 0,
   'percentage': 0,
   'discountType': 'None',
   'shipping': {'isFree': 1, 'price': 0},
   'user': {'userId': 2701300,
    'username': 'Manish_N',
    'title': '',
    'avatar': {'path': 'users/raw/default',
     'name': '2701300_6',
     'slotId': 'default',
     'width': 0,
     'height': 0,
     'version': 6,
     'unattached': 'False',
     'uid': '2701300_6.raw',
     'ext': 'raw'},
    'persona': {'text': 'None', 'type': 'None'},
    'isBanned': 'False',
    'isDeletedOrPendingDeletion': 'False',
    'isUserProfileHidden': 'False'}}}}


Yes this worked perfectly. Do you know why we had to do this preprocessing first and it was not recognised as valid JSON? What form was it in initially?

I cannot answer, without seeing the code which produced this string in the first place.

Please consider the string in this paste bin https://pastebin.com/UtJUxRRt - I believe it is an edgecase that doesn't work with the above solution. I believe it fails at the  Samsung 55\\\" part where for some reason all of the \ are removed and the " is not escaped

Again, I'd need to see the code extracting that string. For that edge case (and actually for TV desriptions containing " and triple backslashes) you can do string = string.replace('false', '0').replace('true', '1').replace('null', '"None"').replace('\\\\', '').replace('\\\\"', '')

I have included the full api response as an update. Here it is for your convenience https://pastecode.io/s/gwf0tcmg - if you have any ideas as how best to parse the initial json here it would be appreciated. Maybe, I shouldn't be using bs4 to parse the HTML within the content in the API response in the first place?
